# How can I debug Python 3 code in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, visual-studio-code

I want to debug a project written in Python 3 in Visual Studio Code, but I can't seem to find any way of specifying interpreter or Python version in the launch.json file.

It works great for Python 2, so the question is, how do I make it work for Python 3?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Python 3 debugging works well also. It is a little confusing as there are two different places to specify the path: **settings.json** and **launch.json**.

I recommend using [Don Jayamanne's Python Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.python). After installing it, you have to [configure the path](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/wiki/Python-Path-and-Version) to the interpreter you want to use it with.

> > Python Version used for Intellisense, autocomplete, linting, formatting, etc.
>
> The same Python interpreter is used for intellisense, autocomplete,
> linting, formatting, etc. (everything other than debugging). The
> standard interpreter used is the first Python interpreter
> encountered in the current path. If a different version is to be used,
> this can be configured in one of two ways:
>
> Configure the path to the python interpreter in the User Settings file
> (settings.json) as follows. Ensure to specify the fully qualified name
> of the python executable. "python.pythonPath":
> "c:/python27/python.exe"
>
> Configure the path to the Python interpreter
> in the Workspace Settings file (settings.json) as follows. Ensure to
> specify the fully qualified name of the Python executable.
> "python.pythonPath": "c:/python27/python.exe" Python Version used for
> debugging
>
> Details on configuration settings for debugging can be found here
> Debugging. Simply provide the fully qualified path to the python
> executable in the "python" setting within the configuration settings
> in the launch.json file as follows:

```
{
    "name": "Python",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "stopOnEntry": true,
    "program": "${file}",
    "pythonPath": "c:/python27/python.exe",
    "debugOptions": [
        "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
        "WaitOnNormalExit",
        "RedirectOutput"
    ]
}
```

Comment: `"debugOptions"` has been removed from the config options in the newer versions

Answer (score 34):

As of September 2016 (according to the GitHub repository documentation of the extension), you can just execute a command from within Visual Studio Code that will let you select the interpreter from an automatically generated list of known interpreters (including the one in your project's virtual environment).

Execute:

```
Python: Select Workspace Interpreter
```

For later version, just:

```
Python: Select Interpreter
```

in the command palette (<kbd>F1</kbd> for Windows, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> for macOS).

Then select one of the Python interpreters shown in a drop down list. And that's it. Your *settings.json* file will be edited automatically to point to the interpreter you selected.

Source: [Don Jayamanne's extension's documentation at GitHub](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/wiki/Miscellaneous#select-an-interpreter)

<sub>Note: Since I couldn't comment to the accepted answer I copied some of [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41657367/6036878).</sub>

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. There's definitely no need to download an extension for this.

Answer (score 3):

We can configure the debug in Python 3 in file *settings.json*:

Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings* (file *~/.config/Code/User/settings.json*) (User Settings)

```
{
  ...
  "python.pythonPath": "python3",
}
```

Also, verify that the *launch.json* file already has the following configuration:

```
"configurations": [
  {
    "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
  },
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a setting trigger within the setting file:

For Python default (which is 2.7 for now)

```
"python.pythonPath": "python",
```

For Python 3:

```
"python.pythonPath": "python3",
```

Use the following command to check the Python version:

```
import sys
  print(sys.version)
```

Comment: Settings file? File `settings.json`?

Answer (score 1):

An extra note for those using the [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) Python distribution by continuum analytics: you may find my experience useful.

I'm using [Don Jayamanne's Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.python-extension-pack) and run the "Select Workspace Interpreter" command, but still found I was getting linting advice for the wrong version of Python.

The fix that worked for me was installing the [Pylint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pylint) package for Anaconda:

```
conda install -c anaconda pylint
```

Answer (score 0):

To debug Python projects in Visual Studio Code, use the *Launch Configuration* as below:

```
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${cwd}/{filename}.py",
        "args" : [
            "--arg1", "arg1-value",
            "--arg2", "arg2-value",
            "--arg3", "arg3-value"
        ],
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
```

Comment: What platform, incl. version, was this tested on? Linux?

Comment: Re *"Launch Configuration"*: What part of what file? And/or, how can it be navigated to in Visual Studio Code?