# Visual Studio Code Code Completion With 3rd Party Python Libraries

Tags: python, ubuntu, beautifulsoup, visual-studio-code, urllib

How to get code completion running for 3rd party libraries (specifically beautifulsoup4 and urllib3) on VSCode?

What I'm trying:

First, I searched for the location of the libraries in terminal:

```
python3
>>>import bs4, urllib3
>>>bs4.__file__
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py'
```

and the same for urllib3. I then put those into my settings.json:

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/__init__.py",
"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/",
"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py",
"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/"
]
```

(At first I had the path with the `__init__.py` part, but I figured that might've been my problem so I got rid of the `__init__` to no avail).

So does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong/how to fix this? Keep in mind I'm running Ubuntu 16.04LTS.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to install Python libraries to your system directory (i.e. to use `pip` with `sudo`). Instead, build a virtual environment and then [configure Visual Studio Code to use it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38073002/354577).

Comment: Hm, I haven't tried this, but I was under the impression VSC would be able to do this out of the box, no?