# How to run python programs in visual studio code in virtualenv

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am currently running python programs in virtualenv but how can I run using visual studio code especially when run/debug is clicked. (Ubuntu)

First I need to be inside the environement this is what I run from terminal **source ~/home/python/bin/activate** and then python test.py where python is pointing to python3.5 in virtualenv

Basically I want to debug by using breakpoints.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but Scrapy has some interactive debugging functionality that may be useful for you.

Comment: @VMRuiz scrapy i can somehow manage but checking with the virtualenv concept

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Virtualenv with Python with Visual Studio Code in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642045/use-virtualenv-with-python-with-visual-studio-code-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please edit launch.json Add Configuration

```
{
            "name": "Attach (Remote Debug)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "remoteRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 3000,
            "secret": "my_secret",
            "host": "localhost"
},
```

Follow link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Comment: but how to be in the environment. I have updated the question

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to follow the SO guidelines to provide a quality answer..

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642045/use-virtualenv-with-python-with-visual-studio-code-in-ubuntu as this represents 2018

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using the [donjayamanne.python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.python) plugin for Visual Studio Code you can set this in the **User or Workspace Settings file (settings.json):**

```
"python.pythonPath": "~/home/python/bin/python"
```

You can access the settings file in Visual Studio Code using File -> Preferences -> Settings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is explained how you can run Visual Studio Code with Python https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python

**EDIT1:**

Windows - Python Virtual Environment And PYTHONPATH with Visual Studio Code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfvuK7US_9s

**EDIT2:**
Ubuntu - http://dacrook.com/setting-up-python-and-virtual-environments-in-visual-studio-code-on-ubuntu/

Comment: link doesn't say about virtualenv concept

Comment: The link for ubuntu now points to a Bitcoin website. Please always give an explanation instead of just liking. Websites are not permanent.