# How execute python command within virtualenv with Visual Studio Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I have created virtual environment named `virualenv`. I have scrapy project and I am using there some programs installed in my `virtualenv`. When I run it from terminal in VSC I can see errors even when I set up my virtual environment via `Ctrl+Shift+P` -> Python: Select Interpreter -> Python 3.5.2(virtualenv). Interpreter works in some way, I can import libs without errors etc, but I am not possible to start my scrapy project from terminal. I have to activate my virtual environment first via `/{path_to_virtualenv}/bin/activate`. Is there a way, how to automatically activate it? Now I am using PyCharm and it is possible there, but VSC looks much better according to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Virtualenv with Python with Visual Studio Code in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642045/use-virtualenv-with-python-with-visual-studio-code-in-ubuntu)

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As I mentioned in my question, this works fine and does not solving my problem. Only way how it works for me is to activate virtualenv first in console and then start code myproject.

Answer (score 1):

One way I know how,

Start cmd
Start you virtual env
(helloworld) \path\etc> code .

It will start studio code in this environment. Hope it helps