# How to access my python virtual env in vscode terminal

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I've created a virtualenv for my django project. And i want to use vscode. But 'workon env_name' is not working in vscode terminal, but its working fine on my command prompt.

Comment: Need more information. What was the error in vscode's terminal? What other research was done on this issue? This might be helpful https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642045/use-virtualenv-with-python-with-visual-studio-code-in-ubuntu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Virtualenv with Python with Visual Studio Code in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642045/use-virtualenv-with-python-with-visual-studio-code-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

do you add `"python.pythonPath": "<your env path>/bin/python3.6"` in settings.json of your vscode?