# How can I get pylint to use python 3 in VS code?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, debugging, visual-studio-code, pylint

I want pylint to use python3 for linting in Visual Studio code on Mac (which has both python 2.7 standard and python 3.6).

I've tried changing the path to the python interpreter as per [How can I debug Python3 code in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36859564/how-can-i-debug-python3-code-in-visual-studio-code), to no avail. I keep getting python2 errors instead of python3 errors.

See [example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6U9T.png) for the problem.

Is there a way I can get pylint to recognize python3 errors?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Pick a xx.py in Visual Studio Coce(VSC)
2. In Status Bar Tap Python 2.7.10 like the [img1]
3. Choose python 3.x like [img2]
4. Command+Q quit VSC, then open VSC again

[image]

[image: img2]

Comment: I found out visual studio already tell us how to change python here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial, it's almost like  my answer, but provide another way: Select Interpreter command on the Command Palette (⇧⌘P)

Comment: I Also found vsc if you choose python3 as default interpreter, then create a new xx.python, it will show a prompt box to guide u to install pylint,  when you choose to install it will execute shell command in terminal: `$ /usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip install -U pylint --userCollecting pylint`

Comment: So simple! yet so hard to locate. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

I finally got it working by installing python3 pylint from the console.

> sudo python3 -m pip install -U pylint

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. The simple solution is to just change the first line of the file `/home/user_name/.local/bin/pylint` from `#!/usr/bin/python2` to `#!/usr/bin/python3`
2. If you want more, you can rename this file to `pylint2` and have a copy `pylint3` where you change the first line to `#!/usr/bin/python3`.

   Now to use pylint3 from command line you just need to type pylint3 instead of pylint.. also change the directory of pylinter in vscode to `/home/user_name/.local/bin/pylint3`

**explanation**

Ok this might be very late and the answer might not be the optimum, but I had the same issue.

By default the path to pylint is `/home/user_name/.local/bin/pylint` that is a simple python script working as the entry point to pylint.. even after installing pylint using pip3 this file is not changed and keeps directing to use python2 and therefore the packages installed by pip2 for python2.

So either have separate entry points for each pylint version, or modify this one manually to use the pylint package installed for python3.